# Get bc to quit without input

Tags: unix, bc

The requirements are as follows:

Using the bc command create a line of code that redirects gpay into bc as the input file and redirects to the output file tgpay to hold the total gross pay. **[The requirement of the Homework is that the bc command is the first element on the command line.]**

Mainly I have got this to work but I cannot meet the requirement in the assignment. Specifically, the bc command is supposed to come first. My code is as follows:

```
echo quit | bc -q gpay > tgpay
echo quit | bc -q npay > tnpay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bc < gpay > tgpay
```

When gpay ends, bc quits because gpay is stdin, and EOF means "quit reading and exit instead" to bc. Which is what your instructor probably wanted to have his students learn.